Gentelella e Sb-admin-2
Gostaria de saber o que exatamente eu preciso pra poder fazer uma aplicação usando os templates mais novos do Gentelella e do Sb-Admin-2... estou ficando meio confuso com isso, especialmente nas partes dos dropdowns. Preciso saber quais plugins preciso pra poder mexer e quais afetam no dropdown, atualmente estou com o popperjs, mas parece estar conflitando

Esta pergunta já foi postada] e lá já foram fornecidas as orientações relevantes. Desta forma, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui para evitar descentralização de informações (mas continua disponível na postagem linkada).
